# How to run one testcase parallelly in two environments with testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

How to run one testcase parallelly in two environments with testng

I have one test case and that need to be run in two environments

here iam using testNG, MAVEN,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium grid`, for parallel execution on single test case.
I suggest you to go through it for basic idea,

Here is sample code to understand:

With the use of `TestNG-Parameters`

```
@Parameters("Browserforlogin")
@BeforeTest
// Parameter will get browser from testng.xml on which browser test to run

public void beforeClass(String myBrowser) throws MalformedURLException {

    if (myBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpathchrome);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (myBrowser.equals("firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverpathfirefox);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

It will launch Chrome and Firefox browser for parallel execution, and it called from `testng.xml` configuration(Which you have to define in your project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
     <test name="demo1">
        <parameter name="myBrowser" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Your class name" />         
        </classes>
    </test> 
    <test name="demo2">
        <parameter name="myBrowser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Your class name" />           
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```